# intersection of two subspaces of a vector space is also a vector space$\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb R^5$be a vector space and $$W_1=\{(0,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\mid x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in \mathbb{R}\}$$and $$W_2=\{(x_6,0,x_7,x_8,x_9)\mid x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9\in \mathbb{R} \}$$be two subspaces of  $\mathbb{R}^5$ then the dimension of $W_1\cap W_2$ is 
according to me its dimension is $3$ as then $W_1\cap W_2$ have elements of the form $$(0,0,x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb{R} \}$$ hence  $W_1\cap W_2$ will be isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^3$ and dimension of$\mathbb{R}^3$ is 3.

Comment: your formatting could use some work, i don't want to edit the rest.

Comment: can someone tell me my ans is right or wrong?

Comment: even before asking for something is correct or not, please edit this a bit so as to become a bit more clear...

Comment: @abc Stop changing the title to: "can someone tell me if my ans is right or wrong? "-- that is getting really annoying. I think your argument, as it stands, is lacking, while I'll say nothing of its validity. Please provide a proof of your claim instead of asking whether or not it is "right" or "wrong".

Comment: @abc : what you have written it is just an answer (Not much explanation) and it is correct.... no complaints (assuming you have justified yourself why it is so)

Comment: @abc I might have told you something before, but I voted to close your post. It is obvious that you're looking for some binary answer. You posted this question in the most incomprehensible form--to the point that 8-10 edits took place. You repeatedly changed the title of your question to "Can you tell me if I'm right or wrong", all the while ignoring our requests for you to edit your post to make it more comprehensible. Ultimately, I edited your entire post, I hope that you do not get what you want.

Comment: sorry sir ,i am a beginner sorry once again

Comment: @abc : don't be sorry, instead try writing more clearly.. Good luck

Comment: sure and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You figured out that they are of the same dimensions.

Linear spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimensions. This claim is shown by considering the bases of these two spaces.